# what was the idea of coming up the name 'servlet': serve + let

Tags: java, servlets

This is not asking about how servlet works, I am just curious about how they came up with the name 'servlet' literally?

Since I am not a native English speaker, I don't get the subtle meaning of the using the word 'serve' and suffix it with 'let'.

Comment: It's diminutive - pig -> piglet, server -> servlet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Java was new in the mid-1990s, one of the features that made it popular on the young world-wide web was applets. The suffix "-let" indicates something that's small. Applet = little application that runs on a website. In the 1990s that was amazing, since websites at that time were mostly not interactive and consisted of only text.

Servlets were invented a few years later, but the name is probably related. A servlet is a little application running on a server, in contrast to an applet which is a little application running on a client (browser).

Comment: A few years is a bit of an exaggeration, Java 1.0 dates from January 1996, and the Servlet 1.0 specification is of December 1996.

Comment: “Applet” was used to mean small apps that ran on top of a runtime engine long before the Web was invented. One example was [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Script_launchers) applets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to view it in the context of the other Java technology called applet, which basically means 'small application' (running in a web browser). I guess that means that servlet should be seen as 'small server', or - as Jesper answers - a small application running on the server.

This can also be inferred from the [`Servlet` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html):

> A servlet is a small Java program that runs within a Web server.

See also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-let for other examples of the let as a diminutive suffix.